# Find a moderator to move my question to another community

Tags: support, questions

I have asked a [question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/canada-permanent-residency-express-entry-and-ontario-nominee-programs) in law community and now I noticed that there is a more specific community for this question ([Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)).

I am wondering where I can find a moderator to move my question to the more appropriate community?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, moderators won't migrate things unilaterally unless:

1. They are blatantly **off-topic** for Law; and
2. They are **on-topic** for the recipient site.

You are welcome to close it with a custom close reason and then flag it for migration once the question is closed. You can also just post the question on the other site.

Comment: This is very different than how folks in cross-validated do it.  why?